# Text not visible when used setAlpha()

Tags: java, android

I am simply trying to make night mode activity but when the background turns black the text is not visible on screen. Text Disappears when switched to Dark Mode. Any solutions?

I tried `tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);` is also not working when the screen is black.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here are the images:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3E0a.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGSm4.png)

Here is the XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.saipriyank.daynight.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_margin="50px"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background_view"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:alpha="0"/>



    <com.mahfa.dnswitch.DayNightSwitch
        android:id="@+id/dayNight"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Java Code:

```
package com.saipriyank.daynight;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mahfa.dnswitch.DayNightSwitch;
import com.mahfa.dnswitch.DayNightSwitchListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DayNightSwitch dayNight = (DayNightSwitch)findViewById(R.id.dayNight);
        final View background_view = (View)findViewById(R.id.background_view);
        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        dayNight.setDuration(450);
        dayNight.setListener(new DayNightSwitchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwitch(boolean isNight) {
                if(isNight){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Night Mode Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tv.setAlpha(0f);
                    background_view.setAlpha(1f);
                }

                else {
                    background_view.setAlpha(0f);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making the TextView invisible by calling `tv.setAlpha(0f)`.

If you want to set the text color white, you can use `tv.setTextColor(Color.White);`